# Bitwise not True (including NaN) in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": range(5), "is_bar": [np.nan, np.nan, False, True, False], "is_foo": [True, False, True, True, False]})
```

Now I want rows of `df` where are foo, but not bar or bar is missing. In other words, this is the desired result:

```
   id is_bar  is_foo
0   0    NaN    True
2   2  False    True
```

I expected `df.loc[df["is_foo"] & ~df["is_bar"]]` to work, but obviously the `np.nan`s are causing `TypeError`.

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need `fillna`:

```
df = df.loc[df["is_foo"] & ~df["is_bar"].fillna(False)]
print (df)
   id is_bar  is_foo
0   0    NaN    True
2   2  False    True
```